# multiple basic-auth in express/node js

Tags: javascript, http, express, authentication, basic-authentication

I'm trying to implement a web app protected by basic HTTP authentication, I managed to make it work throughout the project but I would like to perform a kind of differentiation on multiple levels in the routing of my app. I need to leave a part of my app outside of that authentication, for example a part (/public/:user) and a second part, containing some APIs (/API/android/some1 or /API/android/some2) to communicate with android app I would like to protect it with a second level of authentication. Is it possible to do this?
I read around and made attempts but I get some errors. The function I use for basic authentication in my *app.js* is as follows:

```
...
app.use(function(req, res, next){
 var user = auth(req);

 if (user === undefined || user['name'] !== process.env.BASIC_USR || user['pass'] !== process.env.BASIC_PSW) {
    res.statusCode = 401;
    res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="NodeJS"');
    res.end('Access denied');
 } else {
    next();
 }
});
// index
app.get('/', routes.index);

// home    
app.get('/home', home.view);
...
```

I understand that when I put this function, the whole part of the next router is protected by basic-auth, but as soon as I insert a second part in the next part, later in the code in app.js I have the following:

```
...
app.use(function(req, res, next){
 var user = auth(req);

 if (user === undefined || user['name'] !== process.env.DROID_USR || user['pass'] !== process.env.DROID_PSW) {
    res.statusCode = 401;
    res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="NodeJS"');
    res.end('Access denied');
 } else {
    next();     
 }
});

// API app android 
app.get('/API/get1', get.one);
app.get('/API/get2',get.two);
```

Once I have logged into one of my APIs, I am constantly asked for my credentials, without ever accessing the API result (displaying data from a mysql database). Also, I tried to move the part that I want to make public (/public/:user) before my home (/home) but this shows me an error. When I try to access my home (/home), as I have a dynamic URL in the public part of my app (/public/:user), where user changes according to the number of users, and this number is also used within the code , tells me that this variable is not defined, but I'm not accessing this public part of my app at the moment.

I have two questions to propose:

1) How can I best implement this authentication on two or more levels ?

2) How can I also exclude from the global authentication those parts of routing I wanted to keep public ?